# Disable jaspersoft logging in java application

Tags: java, logging, jasper-reports, log4j

I use log4j for logging, and i want to disable jaspersoft logging. 
I test this code`log4j.logger.net.sf.jasperreports.engine=error` but jasper still printing in console (see below image).

[image: image of console output]

[DefaultExtensionsRegistry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO3UA.png)

Answer (score 1):

The log messages that you are seeing come from Apache Commons Digester, which JasperReports uses to parse JRXMLs.

If you want to disable debug logging for Digester, you would need something like this:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.digester=error
```

Comment: Thanks you. This help me reduce messages. But i still have DEBUG messages when i use jasper coming from this DefaultExtensionsRegistry class.

Comment: Please copy the DefaultExtensionsRegistry messages here.

Comment: I'll add the screenshot to main title. That's image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO3UA.png

Comment: Do you still have log4j.logger.net.sf.jasperreports.engine=error?

Comment: Yes i still have it!

Comment: Change that line to log4j.logger.net.sf.jasperreports=error

Comment: Ohhh sorry for late. i test it but have same result!

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer. I used the code below and there no more log message from jaspersoft. Thanks @dada67.

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.digester=error
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.beanutils=error
log4j.logger.net.sf.jasperreports.engine=error
log4j.logger.net.sf.jasperreports.extensions=error
```